Why won't my PIC turn on an LED?
I was working on flashing an LED for PIC yesterday and made a post about it but couldn't get it to work so I tried getting to the root of the problem by making a program that only turns on the LED and leaves it on. It doesn't do anything else. Here is the main file in MPLAB X IDE.
    #include "CONFIG.h"

    void main(void) {
    
    TRISA2 = 0;
    
    while(1){
        LATA2 = 1;
        
    }
    
    return;
    }

Here is the configuration bits file:

    #ifndef XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H
    #define XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H


    // 'C' source line config statements

    // CONFIG1
    #pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection Bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function 
    on CLKIN pin)
    #pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
    #pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT enabled)
    #pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
    #pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code 
    protection is disabled)
    #pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
    #pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or 
    oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)

    // CONFIG2
    #pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
    #pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or 
    Underflow will cause a Reset)
    #pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage 
    (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
    #pragma config LPBOR = OFF      // Low-Power Brown Out Reset (Low-Power BOR is disabled)
    #pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming 
    enabled)

    // #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
    // Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

    #include <xc.h>
    #endif  /* XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H */

This is driving me crazy. I didn't expect it to be so difficult to turn on an LED. I am beginning to think I may have accidentally overdrawn current from the device and fried the PIC. Here is the pin allocation table if you think it will help:

edit 2: I switched out the PIC with a PIC16f1455 and connected the MCLR pin of the 1455 to VDD and it worked. When I tested the pic, I had the MCLR pin from pickit 5 connected to MCLR. This must've prevented the PIC from working. I am not sure what the MCLR does yet but i will look at it a bit later. @justme might've been right.

Or, there is some fundamental issue with your schematics which you have never shown, or the implementation of the schematics into actual hardware, which you have not shown either. The problem is not always in the code.

so the code looks good?

@xcaliber99 why waste time looking at the code when it is not known how everything is connected ... it could easily be a case of the LED connected to the wrong pin

Its likely that you haven't configured the GPIO pin correctly.

PA2 has 5 possible functions, only one of which is GPIO.
You at least have to clear the appropriate bit in ANSELA. The chip powers up with analog input selected, since it would be bad to do otherwise if the pin was used as an analog input.
Also have a look at APFCON etc. In general it's better to explicitly set such registers rather than hoping the power-up default is right for your application.
Microchip gives you a handy list of which settings/registers you must look at wrt Port A bit 2:


If you want to try it with the MCC, go to the pins tab (it’s in system firmware), on the pin chart mark you’re desired pin as a GPIO output, then on the pin list give it a name and make sure the other options are correct. After generating the code, there will be a pins.h file in the include files that has defines for controlling the pin (turn it on, turn it off, toggle, etc.)

do all the registers for PORT A have to be cleared and set or only APFCON and ANSELA? how come you didn't mention the other registers?

According to the above, for bit 2 (unlike bits 0,1,3,4,5) you don't need to worry bout APFCON. You're dealing with LATA, and TRISA in your code. WUPA2 I don't think matters for an output. Config1 doesn't affect the PortA bit 2 directly. I don't think the prescaler matters if used as a GPIO. This is just  a cursory look, checking in detail is your job. I have pointed out one thing (ANSEL) that is definitely wrong/missing. However you should look at every pin individually to ensure each is configured properly.

pretty sure the chip is fried. it worked a few days ago and the day after, i think i forgot to connect the resistor in series with the LED and it must've fried the PIC. I have pretty much followed your advice to the dot.

Both things can be true.

Pin RA2 powers up as an ADC input.  ANSELA2=0 will make it digital and should fix your issue.
